# How to properly align numbers enclosed in parentheses?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I want to align positive numbers and negative numbers enclosed in parentheses using CSS to achieve the following result:

```
 431,000
 (26,000)
  94,000
 (57,000)
```

Using `text-align:right;` on table cells returns the following result instead:

```
 431,000
(26,000)
  94,000
(57,000)
```

But this is imperfect.

Is there an easy way to do this in such a way that parentheses have not effect on the alignment.

I want to align the numbers so that commas are on top of each other.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think through CSS it is not possible.

Comment: This is not a css issue. It requires a programming language such as php or javascript and html. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever language you choose, you need to test your string output to see if they are negative or positive. Add the brackets to the negatives and add a `&nbsp;` to the end of your positives and still use your text-align: right; Use this if you are using a font where all characters are the exact width like a typewriter.

or add this for a perfect fit otherwise.

```
<span style="visibility: hidden;">)</span>
```

after, this is most likely better anyways.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure: Does a space character has same width as a parenthesis in common fonts?

Comment: If not, I am editing my answer

Comment: I edited my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Much better than using width:someunit!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the commas to be aligned.

One simple solution using html would be to use a table, and align the left most column to the right and the right most column to the left. Collapse the table and remove padding to make it invisible.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="left">431</td><td>,</td><td class="right">000</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">(26</td><td>,</td><td class="right">000)</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">94</td><td>,</td><td class="right">000</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">(57</td><td>,</td><td class="right">000)</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{padding:0;}
.left{text-align:right;}
.right{text-align:left;}
```

Comment: this would align her numbers, I like this as well. Requires a lot of extra code, but works :)